# Ускорение разбиения текста c++

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

Требуется разбить большой файл (1 600 000 строк) на строки и сохранить в коллекцию с уникальными значениями. Подгрузка файла происходит на javascript, полученный из файла текст отправляется в модуль на c++, где происходит разбивка файла по строкам. Созданная коллекция возвращается обратно в js. Код который мне удалось написать:

### C++:

```
#include <node.h>
#include <v8.h>

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace v8;

// Split function --------------------------------------------------------------
template<typename Out>
void split(const std::string &s, char delim, Out result) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.str(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        *(result++) = item;
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, std::back_inserter(elems));
    return elems;
}

// Dictionary parse ------------------------------------------------------------
void Parse(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    Local<Context> context = isolate->GetCurrentContext();

    // Set для записи слов
    Local<Set> Words = Set::New(isolate);

    // Проверка аргумента на тип
    if (!args[0]->IsString()) {
        isolate->ThrowException(
            Exception::TypeError(
                String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Wrong type of first argument")
            )
        );

        return;
    }

    // Конвертим аргумент в строку
    String::Utf8Value arg(args[0]->ToString());
    std::string dictInput = std::string(*arg);

    // Разбиение строки в вектор
    std::vector<std::string> v = split(dictInput, '\n');

    // Перебор вектора
    std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = v.begin();
    for (it; it != v.end(); ++it) {
        // Сохраняем слово в коллекцию
        Words->Add(context, String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, (*it).c_str()));
    }

    // Возвращаем получившийся Set
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(Words);
}

// Module exports --------------------------------------------------------------
void Init(Local<Object> exports, Local<Object> module) {
    NODE_SET_METHOD(module, "exports", Parse);
}

NODE_MODULE(addon, Init)
```

### Javascript:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readDict = require('./build/Release/read-dictionary')

let text = fs.readFileSync('./dictionary.txt', 'utf8')
let WORDS = readDict(text);
```

---

Проблема состоит в том, что код на C++ работает дольше 2200 мс, в то время как аналогичный код на js работает около 1550 мс, что тоже очень долго (и занимает всего десять строк, да):

```
const fs = require('fs');

let WORDS = new Set()

let file = fs.readFileSync('file.txt')
let list = text.split('\n')

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    // Быстрее, чем "WORDS = new Set(list)"
    WORDS.add(list[i++])
}
```

С целью ускорить обработку и была предпринята попытка написания на C++, но пока не очень удачная. ++ я не знаю совсем, сегодня первый день как пишу на нём. Есть какие-то способы ускорить всё это?

Спасибо

Comment: Давайте сформулируем задачу в рамках C++. Это можно сделать? Или тут критично именно взаимодействие с JavaScript? Нельзя ли переформулировать задачу иначе - типа, есть файл на диске. Программа на C++ получает имя этого текстового файла. Она должна сделать то-то и то-то, выход - такой-то. Это возможно?

Comment: @Harry Если брать конкретику и выкинуть отсюда js, то остаётся следующее: Программа на C++ получает блок с текстом, разбивает его на строки и каждую строку отправляет в какой-то метод. Нужно это процесс сделать максимально быстрым

Comment: Если этот блок в памяти, навесить на него `istringstream`, читать строки по одной с помощью `getline` и передавать этому самому методу.

Comment: @Harry Нет, это обычная строка, которая передаётся в аргументы функции. Но про istringstream погуглю

Comment: V8 и так достаточно оптимально работает со строками. Странно, что вы именно это пытаетесь улучшить. Максимум, чего вы добьетесь, ИМХО, лишь незначительное увеличение скорости сплитования строк и то, вряд ли.

Comment: @Sublihim спасибо за комментарий. Я честно говоря как раз таки думал, что js работает медленней хотя бы из-за динамической типизации, поэтому пытался ускорить. Но раз так, то оставлю как есть

Comment: @Sublihim а вообще, при разбиении строки (split) происходит один цикл, при сохранении в Set происходит второй. Тоже самое происходит и js. Я надеялся, что мне хотя бы помогут соединить всё это в один цикл на c++

Comment: V8 "компилит" (JIT) в машинный код. В JS очень много работы со строками. В итоге строковые алгоритмы оптимизированы донельзя. Если вы пишите на ноде - доверьтесь ноде. Вдобавок, хорошо бы попрофилировать, что именно вызывает задержку: работа с файлом или сплитование? И, боюсь просадка будет не в сплитовании.

Comment: Конечно, можно и на плюсах написать достаточно быструю реализацию вашей задачи. Но тут опять-таки надо учитывать, одно дело, вы это делаете на чистом С от и до, другое - все это все-равно как-то задействовано в инфраструктуре ноды

Comment: @Sublihim Сплитование на js занимает ~ 400 мс, цикл, который пихает получившийся массив в Set — ~ 700 мс. Соответственно, было бы лучше их соединить вместе. На js один цикл, перебирающий по буквам и сразу сохраняющий слова в Set работает на порядок дольше чем split и цикл по массиву.

Comment: @Sublihim я думаю то как оно будет работать в ноде уже не важно. Задача в том, что бы максимально ускорить разбиение файла в 1 600 000 строк и передать Set в нод

Comment: В C++ коде, как минимум не надо возвращать вектор по значению `std::vector<std::string> split(...)` передавайте его внутрь ф-ции по ссылке. Это, как минимум, уже сэкономит время на копирование. И т.д. В самом плюсовом коде есть тоже места для оптимизации

Comment: @Sublihim Дело в том, что я c++ не знаю совсем. В принципе за помощью и я обратился сюда поэтому. Я накидал псевдокод из того, что было в js и им руководствовался, собирая куски кода, которые я находил на stackoverflow. Функцию split я нашел тут же, я понимаю что она делает, но плохо понимаю в плане синтаксиса

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz. Я имел ввиду вот это: http://pastebin.com/UwMYAdzT

Comment: @Sublihim Спасибо, теперь понял о чем вы. Но как ни странно, изменений никаких

Comment: @VasyaShmarovoz. Потому, что наверняка, основное время съедается в  другом месте. А в целом, мои предыдущие комментарии в силе: доверьтесь ноде :)

Comment: @Sublihim попробовал убрать функцию сплита и сделал один цикл внутри парсера, выиграл 500 мс. Теперь время одинаковое с нодом, я думаю есть еще куда ускорять. Жалко, никто не подсказал, но спасибо